# Focus component after changing content pane of JFrame

Tags: java, swing, focus

I'm changing my `JFrame`'s content pane and simply want to focus a `JTextField` in the new panel. So I'm doing this:

```
JPanel pNew = new JPanel();
frame.setContentPane(pNew);
frame.revalidate();
frame.repaint();

public JPanel() {
    ...
    tf.requestFocusInWindow();
}
```

When I use `setVisible(false)` and `setVisible(true)` instead of revalidating and repainting my frame, I get my wished effect, but that's not the way I want to do it.

What else happens in `setVisible()` but revalidating and repainting?

Comment: 1. We'd all be much better off if you would create a very small demo program that illustrates your problem for us, an [mcve]. 2. Why not simply swap JPanels via a CardLayout? This type of situation is specifically what it is useful for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it to work simply by putting the `requestFocusInWindow()` call in the button's action listener. As camickr mentioned the call needs to be made after the constructor. Here's an example program showing how I got it to work. Hope it helps!

```
public class PanelRevalidate {
    public JFrame frame;
    public MyPanel panel1, panel2;

    public PanelRevalidate() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        panel1 = new MyPanel(1);
        panel2 = new MyPanel(2);
        frame.setContentPane(panel1);

        panel1.getSwap().addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                frame.setContentPane(panel2);
                frame.revalidate();
                panel2.getTextField().requestFocusInWindow();
            }
        });

        panel2.getSwap().addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                frame.setContentPane(panel1);
                frame.revalidate();
                panel1.getTextField().requestFocusInWindow();
            }
        });

        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setResizable(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new PanelRevalidate();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

And the MyPanel class:

```
public class MyPanel extends JPanel {

    public JTextField tf;
    public JButton swap;
    public JLabel panel_label;

    public MyPanel(int n) {
        tf = new JTextField(25);
        swap = new JButton("Swap");
        panel_label = new JLabel("panel " + n);

        add(tf);
        add(swap);
        add(panel_label);
    }

    public JButton getSwap() {
        return swap;
    }

    public JTextField getTextField() {
        return tf;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This and camickr's hints made it work and understandable for me :)

Answer (score 2):

A [CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) is typically used to swap panels.

However, even the default implementation of `CardLayout` does not set focus on the panel when it is swapped. However you can check out [Card Layout Focus](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/31/card-layout-focus/) which will allow you to request focus on the panel when it is switched.

The `requestFocusInWindow()` method only works on a component that is displayed in a visible frame. So you can't invoke the method in the constructor of the class.

You could use the `RequestFocsListener` found in [Dialog Focus](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2010/03/14/dialog-focus/). It will wait until the panel is added to a visible GUI before generating the event.

Comment: I think CardLayout isn't the solution here. In my new panel I want to display data depending on the selected button and other data from my old panel. So I want to create my panel only after my button gets clicked. In CardLayout I would create all panels on frame creation. But thanks for the hint with the visible frame. That just opens another question: How can I set the textfield's focus after the panel's contructure without making the textfield an object property?

Comment: @Froxx, That was my second suggestion.

Comment: Oh I see. I payed to much attention to your first one. Thanks a lot!